# Redirecting a subfolder to subdomain and keep the url intact

Tags: iis, web-config, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, redirect

I want to (temporary (few months tops)) redirect a subfolder to a subdomain and keep the url intact. This because we are moving our website to different server bit by bit.

We currently have multiple sub applications in IIS like:

> www.ourdomain.com/shoppingcart
>   www.ourdomain.com/backoffice

We want to redirect those to their subdomains:

> shoppingcart.ourdomain.com
>   backoffice.ourdomain.com

To do this we added the following rule to our web.config:

```
<rule name="MovedShoppingcart" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^shoppingcart/([_0-9a-z-/]+)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://shoppingcart.ourdomain.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

This rule works fine for a few samples, but not for sub folders:

> www.ourdomain.com/shoppingcart --> shoppingcart.ourdomain.com
>   www.ourdomain.com/shoppingcart/foo --> shoppingcart.ourdomain.com/foo

The above 2 are fine, but when I add another subfolder it doesn't work:

> www.ourdomain.com/shoppingcart/foo/bar?id=temp --> shoppingcart.ourdomain.com/foo?id=temp

(the missing /bar/)

What is wrong with my rewrite rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When entering the regular expression in regexr the tool indicated an error.

[image]

By escaping the forward slash as  follows the regex should work fine.

```
^shoppingcart\/([_0-9a-z-/]+)
```